# how to get auto complete meaningful parameters in android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get auto generated code with a meaningful parameters in android studio ?

look to this example :

First non meaningful parameters >>

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
```

Second meaningful parameters >>

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have those meaningful parameters only in methods which you define yourself and add it in eclipse/android studio list. Unfortunately you can't do that in the overridden methods already provided by android.

UPDATE:
Source code is required to get proper parameter names in code completion. Android SDK didn't bundle sources until 4.0 platform version (API version 14), since then sources are available out of the box. Go into the `project structure`->`platform settings`->`SDKS` and click on the individual platform and see if you can locate the source in the documentationPath tab.

Comment: why android doesn't put a meaningful names ?

Comment: i looked up my android studio and i am getting the meaningful parameters in there that you are talking about. I will update my answer..